# Using EventBus to pass userID to call API but will not bind response to input field

Tags: vuejs2, axios, vue-router, event-bus

I used an EventBus to pass the UserId to another component (`UpdateStaff`). Then, I want to call an API at `url/api/staffs/{UserId}`, to get the data of that particular user and bind the data to the input fields. I'm able to get the response payload but unable to bind to the input fields.

**UpdateStaff.vue:**

An example of an input field in the template:

```
<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" v-model="data.username">
```

Data properties & created method:

```
data () {
  return {
    data: {
      name: '',
      username: ''
    }
  }
},
created () {
  EventBus.$on('getUserId', (userId) => {
    axios.get(staffUrl + '/' + userId)
      .then((response) => {
        let self = this
        self.data.username = response.data.username
        self.data.name = response.data.name

        console.log(self.data.username)
        // It prints out exactly what i want
        // BUT it doesn't show the data in the input field....?
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
}
```

**Staff.vue:**

Has a vuetable component in it to display all Staffs. After clicking the Update Button, I redirect to the UpdateStaff page via calling an `onActions` method.

```
methods: {
  onActions (action, data) {
    router.push({ path: '/user/UpdateStaff' })
    EventBus.$emit('getUserId', action.data.userId)
  }
}
```

Previously, I was able to display data in input fields with just `axios` alone. However, after adding the `EventBus` with `axios` in it, I was unable to display data in input fields anymore.

How should I go about fixing this issue?

Comment: I edited your question to include the original `let self = this` issue so that my answer (and parts of your question) still make sense. I've updated my answer to address the routing issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not seeing the data update correctly is that `this` is not the Vue instance when you reference it in the `.then` callback.

Put the `let self = this` statement at the very beginning of your `created` hook to be sure you are storing the correct reference to `this`:

```
created () {
  let self = this
  // after this point, `self` will reference the Vue instance even in callbacks

  EventBus.$on('getUserId', (userId) => {
    axios.get(staffUrl + '/' + userId)
      .then((response) => {
        // setting `self` to `this` here doesn't make sense because `this` 
        // is not refering to the Vue instance in this callback

        self.data.username = response.data.username
        self.data.name = response.data.name
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  })
}
```

---

The reason the `getUserId` event isn't being handled when you push to that route is that the `$emit` event is being fired before the `UpdateStaff` component is created (meaning the `$on` handler hasn't been set yet).

To wait for the component to have been created, wrap the `$emit` in a `this.$nextTick` callback:

```
methods: {
  onActions (action, data) {
    router.push({ path: '/user/UpdateStaff' })
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      EventBus.$emit('getUserId', action.data.userId)
    })
  }
}
```

From [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) on the usage of `Vue.nextTick`:

> Defer the callback to be executed after the next DOM update cycle. Use it immediately after you’ve changed some data to wait for the DOM update.

Comment: Hi @thanksd , thanks for your help and resources! But putting `let self = this;` , the data still does not show up in the input field for some reason.

Comment: Can you show your data properties definition and how you are binding them to inputs?

Comment: Hi @thanksd , Data properties: `data () { return { data: name: '', username: '' } }`                                 An example of an input: `<input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Username" v-model="data.username">`                                         I don't know whether this information will help but when I did it without the EventBus, i could get the data to display in the input fields. But after putting axios in the EventBus {}, then the data wouldn't show up in the input fields anymore. Any idea?

Comment: Please edit your question to include that. And does your code look exactly like my updated answer?

Comment: I have updated my question! And yes, it does. @thanksd

Comment: Are you actually triggering the event bus's `getUserId` event anywhere? Because if so, then your code should work. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/L7e5fgq2/

Comment: Appreciate you doing up the jsfiddle! I have checked my code against your jsfiddle and it's almost identical. After trying an error, i think i finally found the problem (but still can't solve it). It has something got to do with my `router.push()` I followed your jsfiddle, i was able to get the data into my input. However, going back to my original code with the `router.push()`. The data didn't show up in the input fields anymore. _Just updated my question to show the onAction method_ @thanksd

Comment: Thank you for your superb explanation! Finally understood the reason behind my problem. Now it completely works! Thank you for your help :-) Appreciate it!